# Contact form using jquery, ajax, and mailer php script does nothing when clicking submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a contact form on my website and I'm trying to implement send to email functionality when the user enters information and clicks submit. So, ideally the information in the contact form should be emailed to me after submit.  What I'm trying to implement uses jQuery, AJAX, and a PHP mailer script I got from the tutorial located here:  http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form

The problem is when I click Submit, nothing happens, nothing is redirected stating there is an error or telling me it's successful. Only thing to happen is the form fields are cleared.  I read in the comments on that site a certain version of PHP is required for the mailer script, but I'm not too experienced with PHP and back-end development.  I know something's missing, just not sure what.  Seems like some communication is missing and I'm not getting any javascript errors.  All of the id and name attributes match in my .html, .js and .php files.  Files are also uploaded in Bluehost (currently where site is hosted).  Do I need to install a new PHP version somewhere in Bluehost?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
//e.preventDefault();
$("button").click(function(e) {

    var ajax = {
        isSubmitting: false,
        send: function() {
            if(ajax.isSubmitting == false) {

                ajax.isSubmitting = true;
                var userName = $("input [name=contact-name]"); 
                var userEmail = $("input [name=contact-email]"); 
                var userWebsite = $("input [name=contact-website]"); 
                var userMessage = $("input [name=contact-message]"); 

                if(userName === "" || userEmail === "" ||     userWebsite    === "" || userMessage === "") {
                    alert("Please fill out all required fields.");
                } 
                else {
                    $.post("mailer3.php", {
                        name: userName,
                        email: userEmail,
                        website: userWebsite,
                        message: userMessage

                    }, function(data) {

                        ajax.isSubmitting = false;

                    });
                }
            }
            else alert("Send only 1 email at a time.");
        }
    }

});
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

//PHP Mailer Script
if(count($_POST) > 0) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $website = $_POST['website'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $header = "Content-Type: text/html\r\nReply-To:: $email\r\nFrom: $name <$email>";

    $body = 
    @"Email sent from ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." at ".date("d/m/Y     H:i",time())."<br />
    <hr />
    $message
    <hr />
    Email end";

    if(mail("andrew@ajcwebcreations.com", "You have a new message.", $message, $header)) {
        die("true");
    } else {
        die("Error sending message.");
    }
}


?>
```

Andrew

Comment: Please post your code which you are working on.

Comment: is this the whole php-code? or did something get lost posting it here? cause it's missing some code - it wont work this way

Comment: This is all the PHP code.  I have very little experience with PHP and was going by the tutorial I found online.  But yes, this is the php code.  It does seem like something's missing especially since nothing happens when clicking submit.  any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: When clicking the submit button, make sure to watch in console what the php file is returning, and if it's getting posted at all.

Comment: Good idea!  I did and for the POST in the Post tab is showing the correct parameters along with the correct input.  The Response tab is empty.  Correct me if I am wrong, but it's "POST"ing just not sending.  Any tell-tale information I should be looking for in the headers?  Thanks!

Comment: So I just started over deciding to try and get the email to send, which I did using the revised code above.  But the input does not come through in the email, only the subject.  Any critique or suggestions would be helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Started over from scratch and got email to send, but input isn't included in the email only the subject.  Maybe going to post another question for that issue if I can't figure it out.  Thanks to all those who took the time to add input!